Prove that there exists $ \xi \in [a, b] $ such that $ \int_a^b f g \, dx = g(a) \int_a^\xi f \, dx + g(b) \int_\xi^b f \, dx. $
Let $ f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R} $ and $ g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be functions such that $ f$ is continuous and $ g $ is monotonic, continuously differentiable, and non-negative on the interval $ [a, b] $. Prove that there exists $ \xi \in [a, b] $ such that
$$
\int_a^b f g \, dx = g(a) \int_a^\xi f \, dx + g(b) \int_\xi^b f \, dx.
$$
I thing we should define: $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}fdt$$
And eventually use the mean value theorem on $ F $; however, I don't know how to relate $ F(x)$ with:
$$H(x)=\int_{a}^{x}fgdx$$
Technically if $
\int_a^b f g \, dx = g(a) \int_a^\xi f \, dx + g(b) \int_\xi^b f \, dx
$:
$$H(b)=(g(a)-g(b))F(\xi)+g(b)F(b)$$
Maybe in some way that I’m not seeing, it can be derived from the Mean Value Theorem. Moreover, to apply the Mean Value Theorem, we need to be clear about how the product behaves, because although I can assume

g is monotonically increasing with $g(a)\leq g(x)\leq g(b)$, I don't know between which values $f(x)g(x)$ lies, since $f$ could be negative.

Look up the "Second Mean Value Theorem for Integrals".

This is easily proved using Riemann-Stieltjes integration assuming only that  $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ is monotonic.
Defining $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$, as you have, it is straightforward  to show that
$$\tag{1}\int_a^b f(x) g(x)\, dx= \int_a^b g dF = g(b)F(b) - g(a)F(a) - \int_a^b F \, dg,$$
where the second equality follows from integration-by-parts for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.
Since $F$ is continuous and $g$ is monotonic, the first mean value theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals implies that there exists $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that
$$\tag{2}\int_a^bF\, dg = F(\xi)[g(b)-g(a)] $$
Noting that $F(a) = 0$ and substituting with (2) into (1) we get
$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x)\, dx= g(b)F(b) - g(b)F(\xi) + g(a)F(\xi) \\= g(a)\int_a^\xi f(x) \, dx+ g(b)\int_a^b f(x) \, dx - g(b)\int_a^\xi f(x) \, dx\\= g(a)\int_a^\xi f(x) \, dx+ g(b)\int_\xi^b f(x) \, dx $$
